# How can I know if I'm using terra or aqua satellite

Tags: modis, sentinel-snap, terra

I'm using the MOD09GA product (mainly using band 6). I want to work **only** with the data from the Terra satellite; how can I know if the image is Terra or Aqua?

I looked in the MODIS Surface Reflectance User's Guide [1](https://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdf/MOD09_UserGuide_v1.4.pdf). In the user's guide, they wrote *"The "MOD" prefix should be taken as referring to the dataset in general, **not** to Terra-derived data in particular. All programs discussed in this document process either Terra- or Aqua-derived data."*

I also looked in the meta-data using SNAP and didn't find the satellite reference. Where can I see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quote of the user manual means that they used Terra product names as examples but the same would apply to their Aqua counterparts, so it is just a way to avoid repeating the same information twice.

Here is the full quote (the info you are looking for is in the section title):

> **4.5. All I've seen in this document is "MOD", meaning Terra -- what about Aqua (“MYD”)?**
> The "MOD" prefix should be taken as referring to the datasets in general, not to Terra-derived data in
> particular. All programs discussed in this document process either Terra- or Aqua-derived data. All
> datasets referred to in this document will be referred to as "MOD" data, but meaning either Terra- or
> Aqua-derived data.
> No combined Terra+Aqua MOD09 products are available or planned for.

It is confirmed by information found on the NASA website: MOD09GA is the Terra product (https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/missions-and-measurements/products/MOD09GA) and the Aqua equivalent is named M**Y**D09GA (https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/missions-and-measurements/products/MYD09GA).

So with MOD09GA you are using exclusively Terra data.

Comment: Thank you all for your insightful answers! I understand how to work with the data!